# Oracle SQL Joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join two tables from a different schema into one table.... This is my query. I keep getting an error saying that it is missing right parenthesis. Can anyone help me figure this out? I have tried every possible solution that I can think of.  I don't believe that it is missing one but it won't work. Here is my query:

```
create view  customers_g2 as 
select (    
(schema1.INTX.CUST_ID, 
schema1.INTX.CUST_NAME,
schema1.INTX.CUST_GENDER,
schema1.INTX.CUST_STATE,
schema1.INTX.COUNTRY_ID)
Join
select (KWEKU.KM_CUSTOMERS_EXT.CUST_ID, 
schema2.EXT.CUST_AGE, 
schema2.EXT.CUST_EDUCATION, 
schema2.EXT.MARRIED, 
schema2.EXT.NO_OF_CHILDREN, 
schema2.EXT.RACE, 
schema2.EXT.INCOME, 
schema2.EXT.CHECKING_BAL, 
schema2.EXT.SAVINGS_BAL, 
schema2.EXT.ASSETS, 
schema2.EXT.HOUSES)
from schema1.INTX,schema2.EXT 
where schema1.INTX.CUST_ID = schema2.EXT.CUST_ID);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try change

```
create view  customers_g2 as (
                             ^ remove this parenthesis
```

to

```
create view  customers_g2 as
```

**UPDATE:** Better change the whole thing to

```
CREATE VIEW  customers_g2 
AS
SELECT i.CUST_ID, 
       i.CUST_NAME,
       i.CUST_GENDER,
       i.CUST_STATE,
       i.COUNTRY_ID,
       e.CUST_AGE, 
       e.CUST_EDUCATION, 
       e.MARRIED, 
       e.NO_OF_CHILDREN, 
       e.RACE, 
       e.INCOME, 
       e.CHECKING_BAL, 
       e.SAVINGS_BAL, 
       e.ASSETS, 
       e.HOUSES
  FROM schema1.INTX i JOIN
       schema2.EXT e ON i.CUST_ID = e.CUST_ID
```

*The only thing that doesn't fit is*

```
KWEKU.KM_CUSTOMERS_EXT.CUST_ID
```

*It's unclear why do you need this field from third schema*

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I accidently put that in there

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is so wierd..
Is this what you want?

```
create view  customers_g2 as 
select 
schema1.INTX.CUST_ID, 
schema1.INTX.CUST_NAME,
schema1.INTX.CUST_GENDER,
schema1.INTX.CUST_STATE,
schema1.INTX.COUNTRY_ID,
schema2.EXT.CUST_ID, 
schema2.EXT.CUST_AGE, 
schema2.EXT.CUST_EDUCATION, 
schema2.EXT.MARRIED, 
schema2.EXT.NO_OF_CHILDREN, 
schema2.EXT.RACE, 
schema2.EXT.INCOME, 
schema2.EXT.CHECKING_BAL, 
schema2.EXT.SAVINGS_BAL, 
schema2.EXT.ASSETS, 
schema2.EXT.HOUSES
from schema1.INTX,schema2.EXT 
where schema1.INTX.CUST_ID = schema2.EXT.CUST_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

The extraneous parenthesis causing your problem is the one near the first `select`:

```
create view  customers_g2 as (
select ( -- here
(schema1.INTX.CUST_ID,
```

Also, the parens around the part after `as` are not strictly necessary (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#i2171191)).

And you may want a different kind of join:

```
create view customers_g2 as
  select ...long long list of all your columns...
  from schema1.INTX inner join schema2.INTX
  on schema1.INTX.CUST_ID = schema2.EXT.CUST_ID;
```

(Warning: Everything I know about joins comes from [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html); call me out if I'm wrong.)